# Receive asynchronous data in javascript

Tags: javascript, bash, udp, qml, ipc

I'm using an Linux embedded device that can only run QML/Javascript items. There are **no compilers available, no Python, no curl, no Node.js, no package managers**... But I can write bash scripts.

I need to send asynchronous data from a bash script to the QML/JS objects.
Until now I did the opposite: the JS reads a file created from the bash script:

Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
stty -F /dev/ttyS1 115200 -echo
echo "Receiver is listening..."

file="/dev/ttyS1"

while read -r line; do
  echo "$line"
  target=${line:0:1}
  echo "$target"
  if [ "$target" = "C" ]; then
    echo "${line#?}" > /tmp/file1
  elif [ "$target" = "D" ]; then
    echo "${line#?}" > /tmp/file2
  fi
done < "${file}"
```

QML/JS:

```
function request(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var timer = Qt.createQmlObject("import QtQuick 1.1; Timer {interval: 500; repeat: false; running: true;}", root, "TimerTimeout");

    timer.triggered.connect(function(){
        xhr.abort();
        _timeout = true
    });

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            timer.running = false;
            timer.destroy();
            _timeout = false
            callback(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };

    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.send();
}
```

but it's not useful for *asynchronous* data, because due the polling time I can lose something or get duplicate of already read stuff.

I'm looking for another way to send bytes from a bash script to the QML/JS items. I'm able to send UDP packets from bash:

```
echo "Hello world!" > /dev/udp/192.168.1.10/6188
```

but I don't know how to receive them in JS.
Are there other ways to achieve the same goal?

Comment: The best way is to write some extension in C++ which will create UDP socket waiting for the data and then will pass it ti QML.

Comment: As said, there are *no compilers*. Otherwise there were no problems at all!

Comment: Just out of interest, how Qt was compiled for the platform?

Comment: The manufacturer built a Yocto environment and cross-compiled Qt.

Comment: I think you should look in the direction of custom extension. I mean if you know what is platform, Qt version etc you can build an extension with cross-compiler and then install it in the target platform. Another workaround ...maybe WebSocket, but I see you use QtQuick1.